# error in await useFetch is always null on page reload

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I got something I don't understand in Nuxt v3 (RC-3).

I created a page, which should immediately load data from the API. This is how I do that:

```js
<template>
    <nuxt-layout name="blank">
        //...
    </nuxt-layout>
</template>
<script setup>

const {data: verification, error } = await useFetch(`/proxy/api/does-not-exist`, {
    server: false,
    credentials: "include",
});

if (error.value) {
    //empty on page reload (F5), even if the ajax-call returns 404, 401, 403 or 422, but not empty, if I navigate through Nuxt-link to this page
} else {
    // ...
}
</script>
```

Now the strange thing is: This works fine, if I go to that page using a `nuxt-link`. The `error` is reported correctly and I can handle it in the if-statement.

But if I directly go to the page by pasting a link to the browsers address bar or if I press F5, the response is **still** 404, but the `error.value` is empty.

Now if I wrap it into a `setTimeout`, the problem is gone:

```
setTimeout(async () => {
    const {data, error, pending } = await useFetch(`/proxy/api/does-not-exist`, {
        server: false,
        credentials: "include",
    });

    console.log(data,error,pending);

    console.log(error.value) //is always showing the correct error value
});
```

I don't understand that. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: You can read more about this behaviour [here]
(https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/13805#issuecomment-1397317193) . 
To solve the problem you can set immediate to false and use refresh() to  trigger useFetch manually:


`const { data, refresh } = useFetch(url, { server: false,immediate: false}); 

await refresh(); 

if (error.value) { //handle errors}`